# how to config Laravel 6 in subfolder domain?

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, redhat, subdirectory

I have a Laravel 6 app which is working fine locally on redhat apache.

my client setting the domain and must using /abc ater the domain
i.e  domain.or/abc

i put my root folder into /var/www/abc/

In config/app.php I have

'url' => 'h t t ps :// domain.or/abc',

In pfi/public/.htaccess I have

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /abc

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can access domain.or/abc and the page loads (without styles, images, ...). But all the other links to pages, images, css, js, ... are wrong. For example, they link to

domain.or/css/style.css

instead of linking to

domain.or/PFI/css/style.css

i.e., "PFI" is missing from all the links.

If I go to

domain.or/abc/login

i got 403 error, but if domain.or/login, page load without css,js

and if i open css,js file manually by copy the link to the new tab
i.e domain.or/abc/css/style.css the css dont load, it only show the main page instead of css scripts

Answer (score 0):

in order to fix this issue:

1. ensure that inside .env file `APP_URL=https://domain.or/PFI`
2. ensure the same for `config/app.php` file `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://domain.or/PFI'),`
3. edit your `public/index.php` you have to change the path of these to line to be consistent with the actual path

```
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../path_to_public_folder/bootstrap/app.php';
    
    require __DIR__.'/../path_to_public_folder/vendor/autoload.php';
```

4. in .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
    # Redirect http to https 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Prevent click jacking
        Header set X-Frame-Options Deny
        Header set X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: hi item 1 and 2 have same value,
for items 3
my current path is /var/www/folder

in folder, app,bootstrap,config, public,resources etc, so except folder public, must i move other folder to /var/www?

Comment: no just edit index.php file   ` $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../folderName/bootstrap/app.php';`
    
   ` require __DIR__.'/../folderName/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: thank u for ur helping bro, i already get my answer on my post

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

The changes i did:(my apps folder is laravel)

1. create folder on /var/www/ same with ur subfolder domain, sudo mkdir PFI
2. Create softlink: ln -s /var/www/laravel/public  /var/www/PFI
3. Update httpd.conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/PFI
    Redirect permanent / https://xxx/PFI

<Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName XXX
DocumentRoot /var/www/PFI
</VirtualHost>
```

4. update on my layouts with
5. and all my css,js change to <href ="css/style.css">